# The Queen of Starts - Is Her Bark Worse Than Her Bite?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Each tile belongs to at least one as-yet-unknown category but which belongs where and why?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Venn diagram should be resolved like this:

> [image: Solved Venn diagram]

The ellipses represent:

> Left: **Trees, once the initial 'S' is removed**
>  (S)ASH, (S)OAK, (S)PEAR, (S)TEAK
>
>  Right: **Food items, once the initial 'S' is removed**
>  (S)CREAM, (S)HAM, (S)MASH, (S)PEAR, (S)TART, (S)TRIPE
>
>  (S)PEAR is the only item appearing in the central crossover section, with 'PEAR' being both the name of a tree and the name of its fruit.

As for the title:

> There are so many hints hidden here! 'Bark' suggests trees, 'Bite' suggests something to eat, 'Starts' is a reference to initial letters, and 'The Queen of Starts' is a veiled reference to the nursery rhyme in which 'The Queen of Hearts, she made some tarts...' with 'tart' here being one of the hidden words.

Comment: Bravo - I knew the second I pressed send who it would be!!!

Comment: And in _Alice in Wonderland_, the Queen of Hearts is noted for chopping off heads, here the initial letters 'S'. (Also, we're chopping off the "start" of each word.)